# How to fetch data from Api into listview?

Tags: android, android-activity

When i am trying to call the method "refresh" of main activity from another Api class,the method was called and also it shows some fatal errors.And it didn't change the adapter values.Can anyone give any idea to clear that.?

```
package com.example.hotspot;

import com.example.hotspot.HotspotApi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HotSpot extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    ListView listview;
    HotspotAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hot_spot);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new HotspotAdapter(this);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        new HotspotApi(adapter).execute();

    }

    public void refresh() {

        System.out.println("refresh() is called");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hot_spot, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

hotspot.java

```
package com.example.hotspot;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.hotspot.HotspotModel;
import com.example.hotspot.HotspotAdapter;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class HotspotApi extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> implements
        Icommon {

    public Boolean IsServerErr = false;
    private JSONArray response_array;
    String url = "some url";
    HotspotAdapter adapter;
    HotSpot hot;

    public HotspotApi(HotspotAdapter adapter) {

        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getresult();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        hot=new HotSpot();
        hot.refresh();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    void getresult() {

        InternetManager manager = new InternetManager(url);
        String category_jsonresponse = manager.URLRequest();
        if (!manager.IsServerConn) {
            IsServerErr = true;
        }
        if (category_jsonresponse != null) {
            System.out.println("Hotspot_jsonresponse" + category_jsonresponse);
            try {
                response_array = new JSONArray(category_jsonresponse);
                for (int i = 1; i < response_array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject image_object = response_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    HotspotModel h = new HotspotModel();
                    h.setId(image_object.getString("id") == null ? ""
                            : image_object.getString("id"));
                    h.setContent(image_object.getString("content") == null ? ""
                            : image_object.getString("content"));
                    h.setImg(image_object.getString("img") == null ? ""
                            : image_object.getString("img"));
                    h.setName(image_object.getString("name") == null ? ""
                            : image_object.getString("name"));
                    arraylist.add(h);


                }
                System.out.println("HotspotModelsize() is " + arraylist.size());

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

HotspotAdapter.java

```
package com.example.hotspot;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HotspotAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Icommon{
    private TextView textview;
    private View view;
    ImageView imageview;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public HotspotAdapter(Context context ){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylist.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (arg1 == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        } else {
            view = arg1;
        }

        textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
        textview.setText(arraylist.get(arg0).getName());




        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your logcat. you need to call super first in onPostExecute() super.onPostExecute(result);  
    hot=new HotSpot();
    hot.refresh();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `HotSpotApi` class you are creating a new `HotSpot` activity, this seems wrong. I guess that you are getting json data from internet and load it into a `listview`.

Solution:

In HotspotApi change following instead of calling activity method:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       adapter.notfiyDatasetChanged();
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

hot=new HotSpot(); ?? you cannot use like that! HotSpot is an activity, should be called by Framework for example, activitymanager. Or use startActivity() to show a activity.

Refresh method (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();) will result in refresh of UI. However, hot = new HotSpot() will not call onCreated() method,which means the UI is not created. So it definitely results in the fatal error.

I'd never see anyone call an Activity with new operator.

You should reference the common process about how use a activity and adapter.